# Symfony: Routing 'secure' and 'login' actions to another application

Tags: authentication, symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

Suppose we have 3 apps - `appMain`, `app1` and `app2`.

Applications 1 and 2 are protected, they have `is_secure: true` and everything works fine with sfDoctrineGuard plugin.

A behavior I want to achieve is when a user is not authenticated, current application to forward him to another one, say `appMain` with defined module and action.

Is that possible? Or can someone tell me where to dig about security mechanisms in symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I got this working. First, application forwards to secure module/action and in that action it redirects to an url of main application, that handles authentication and redirects back again.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Make absolute url and redirect there (["Keep It Simple, Stupid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

Comment: I know, but I thought there's another, native way to do this. After some digging, I did it by myself.

Comment: try to use this swCrossLinkApplicationPlugin (I never used it before) plugin for this task. Though I think this solution is too complicated for you. GL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the standard apps/frontend then in apps/frontend/config there will be a file settings.yml

in here in the default section do as follows

```
default:
  .actions:
    error_404_module:       content
    error_404_action:       404

    login_module:           security
    login_action:           login
```

this will then redirect to security/login (or whatever you call the module and the templates)

I usually set the top level apps/frontend/config/security.yml to ..

```
default:
  is_secure: true
```

this secures the whole site, then in any publicly accessible modules, in this case security create a config.yml and set as follows

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```

you will then need to store the fact that authenticated is true when the user logs in as follows

```
$this->getUser()->setAuthenticated(true);
```

[edit] should point out i am not using sfDoctrineGuard

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question which is about using a different *application* for security checks, rather than a module within the current application.

Comment: But his last line said "Or can someone tell me where to dig about security mechanisms in symfony?"